# Why PG 13 does not allow deferring statement trigger constraints?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, constraint, postgresql-13

I noticed in PG 13 docs that only row constraint triggers can be deferrable.

Why not statement constraint triggers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why? Because no one implemented it.

My guess is that since statement level triggers have been implemented recently, this feature was left for a later stage.